# About an assignment in implementation of Stack in CoreFX

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

In [corefx/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/Stack.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/Stack.cs) you can find this code:

```
public T Peek()
{
    int size = _size - 1;
    T[] array = _array;

    if ((uint)size >= (uint)array.Length)
    {
        ThrowForEmptyStack();
    }

    return array[size];
}
```

The question is why they defined `array` and not using `_array`? The same goes in `Push()` and `Pop()`.

Edit: Not happened in `Peek()` of `Queue`.

Comment: My guess would be thread safety, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

The cool thing about GitHub is that you can just look at who, when, and why changes were made.

According to the [commit](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/commit/36ae61031f94c7d92ce8750c088bfa640b5ccb1e#diff-6602265b31f025918caec8ed4f929955) that made this change, it was necessary (at least at that time) to eliminate a bounds check that started happening in .NET Core 2.1.